# Angular JS On ng-change Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jqwidget

I have 2 Java script files with different ng-app modules and different controllers.
I have imported these 2 files into one html.
On-click and on-init data is getting updated in the browser .But on date change , Updated data is coming from server *$scope.crr*  is getting updated but not displayed in browser. Please let know what i have missed.

```js
File 1:controller.js
var helloAjaxApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
helloAjaxApp.controller("MenuCtrl", [ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  
    $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";

    $scope.getmenu = function() {
        $http({
            url : 'menu',
            method : "GET"
        }).then(function(response) {
           
            $scope.menus = response.data;
            
        });
 
    };
} ]);

helloAjaxApp.controller("BranchCtrl", [ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  
    $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";

    $scope.getbranch = function() {
        $http({
            url : 'branch',
            method : "GET"
        }).then(function(response) {
           
            $scope.branch = response.data;
            
        });
 
    };
} ]);

var today = new Date();
var dd = null;
var mm = null; 
var yyyy=null;
if(today.getDate()<10)
    {
        dd="0"+today.getDate();
    }
    else
        {
       dd=today.getDate();
        }
    
if(today.getMonth()+1<10)
    {
        mm=today.getMonth()+1;
        mm='0'+mm;
    }
    else
        {
          mm=today.getMonth()+1;
        }
yyyy = today.getFullYear();
var date=yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
helloAjaxApp.controller("CrrdayCtrl", [ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
    $scope.getcrrday = function() {
      var x;
      if(typeof($scope.date)!="undefined")
       {
       var a=JSON.stringify($scope.date);
       $scope.x=a;
          }
      else
       {
       $scope.x=date;
       }
        $http({
            url : 'crrday',
            method : "POST",
            data : {
                'date' : $scope.x+''
            }
        }).then(function(response) {
        
           $scope.crr = response.data;
         
           
    });
 };
}]);

helloAjaxApp.controller('mytime', function($scope, $interval) {
   $scope.theTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
   $interval(function () {
       $scope.theTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
   }, 1000);
 });
 
  
  
File 2:JQcontroller.js
var today = new Date();
var dd = null;
var mm = null; 
var yyyy=null;
if(today.getDate()<10)
    {
        dd="0"+today.getDate();
    }
    else
        {
       dd=today.getDate();
        }
    
if(today.getMonth()<10)
    {
        mm=today.getMonth();
        mm='0'+mm;
    }
    else
        {
          mm=today.getMonth();
        }
yyyy = today.getFullYear();
var JQDemo = angular.module("jq", ["jqwidgets"]);
JQDemo.controller("dateController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.dateInputSettings =
    {
       
        width: 200,
        height: 30
    }
    $scope.date = new Date(yyyy, mm, dd);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>X</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JQ/scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JQ/scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JQ/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JQ/jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JQ/jqwidgets/globalization/globalize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JQ/jqwidgets/jqxcalendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JQ/jqwidgets/jqxdatetimeinput.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JQ/jqwidgets/jqxangular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JQ/scripts/demos.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/JQControllers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="JQ/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/test.css" />
<script>
//angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("App2"), ['jq']);
angular.module("CombineModule", ["myApp", "jq"]);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Enrollment System</h1>
<div ng-app="CombineModule"> 
   <div ng-init="getmenu()" ng-controller="MenuCtrl" >
      <nav id="main_nav">
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="menu in menus"><a href="{{menu.url}}">{{menu.name}}</a>
            <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="submenu1 in menu.submenus"><a href="{{submenu1.url}}">{{submenu1.name}}</a>
                <ul>
                  <li ng-repeat="submenu2 in submenu1.submenus"><a href="{{submenu2.url}}">{{submenu2.name}}</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      
   <div ng-controller="mytime"> 
   <h4 align="right"><a href="Login.html">Logout</a></h4>
<h3 align="right">{{theTime}}</h3>
</div>  
      
    </div>  
      
 <div  id="widgets" align="left"> 
 <table class="outer">
 
 <tr><td style="color:white;">Quick Status</td></tr>
 <tr>
 
    <td>
    <div ng-init="getbranch()" ng-controller="BranchCtrl">
 <table class="inner">
 <th><button ng-click="getbranch()"><img  align="right" src="images/refresh.jpg" alt="refresh" height="16" width="16"></button>Branch Details</th>
   <tr> <td>
Locations
 </td></tr>
  <tr> <td>
{{branch.locations}}
 </td></tr>
  <tr> <td >
Registered BC/Agents
 </td></tr>
  <tr> <td>
{{branch.bc}}
 </td></tr>
  <tr> <td>
Active BC`s
 </td></tr>
  <tr> <td>
{{branch.activebc}}
 </td></tr>
 </table>
 </div>
 </td>
 
  <td>
  <div ng-init="getcrrday()" ng-controller="CrrdayCtrl">
 <table class="inner">
  <th><button ng-click="getcrrday()"><img  align="right" src="images/refresh.jpg" alt="refresh" height="16" width="16"></button>Today`s Analysis</th>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <div ng-controller="dateController">
  <div ng-controller="CrrdayCtrl">
  <jqx-date-time-input ng-model="date" jqx-settings="dateInputSettings" data-ng-change="getcrrday()"></jqx-date-time-input>
  </div>
  </div>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr> <td>
Enrollments
 </td></tr>
  <tr> <td>
{{crr.enrollments}}
 </td></tr>
   <tr> <td>
Accounts Opened
 </td></tr>
  <tr> <td>
{{crr.accountsopened}}
 </td></tr>
 </table>
 </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div> 
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems ok at first glance. Are you sure that $scope.crr is getting updated after the click?

Comment: Yes, i got the answer now, i was using one controller twice